Fatal Error in logs due to invalid Mailing URLs
We've been seeing a lot of fatal errors like these in the Drupal logs:
https://site-name.com/civicrm/mailing/url?f=3852&pia=7485065
https://site-name.com/civicrm/mailing/url?b=0996&uca=6849452
https://site-name.com/civicrm/mailing/url?ecb=7313683&p=4945
https://site-name.com/civicrm/mailing/url?e=6657&eia=6536580
https://site-name.com/civicrm/mailing/url?a=8908&gwa=1233387
https://site-name.com/civicrm/mailing/url?ked=6931429&s=6273
https://site-name.com/civicrm/mailing/url?nwc=8146203&v=1692

This not only happens with the civicrm/mailing/url but also with mailing view URLs with invalid query strings:
/civicrm/mailing/view?bmd=275&cdvdx=9&dg=02f7240e4826d64082fb10d6cdb210c9_8725402424_1257&wd=4654
/civicrm/mailing/view?aye=945&ba=55dc673b8037ca5ac89cd029101ecae4_7401266365_0191&cbocc=6&xd=7361
/civicrm/mailing/view?ay=5c5aac98683334c982ec357a45a3dfa2_2908772434_6546&be=4894&bee=051&kcbfz=7
/civicrm/mailing/view?be=4397&bi=63a6635f77421d11734983645951d410_8439894732_8682&ejc=244&xbrcj=8

I checked several newsletters from the site and only see links like civicrm/mailing/url?u=123&.. (which is valid), not these other strange ones.
None of our clients have reported issues with invalid URLs in the mailings they've received.
I'm not sure where these URLs are coming from. Could it be an external script calling random mailing URLs?
Has anyone else experienced this problem?
Full Backtrace
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [ "message" => "Could not find valid value for id" "code" => null "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#3123 
#message: "Could not find valid value for id" 
#code: 0 
#file: "/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Request.php"
#line: 98 
#cause: null -_trace: null -errorData: array:1 [ "error_code" => 0 ] trace: { 
/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Request.php:98 { …} 
/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Mailing/Page/View.php:69 { …} 
/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:333 { …} 
./vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …} 
/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …} 
/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Civicrm.php:88 { Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke($args) › ob_start(); › $content = \CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke($args); › $output = ob_get_clean(); } 
/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Controller/CivicrmController.php:83 { …} Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main() {} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php:123 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php:627 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php:124 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php:97 { …} 
/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:181 { …} 
/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:76 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php:58 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php:48 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ContentLength.php:28 { …} 
/web/core/modules/big_pipe/src/StackMiddleware/ContentLength.php:32 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php:48 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php:51 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/AjaxPageState.php:36 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/StackedHttpKernel.php:51 { …} 
/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:704 { …} 
/web/index.php:19 { …} } } ]

